# I am getting error:(Cross-Origin Request Blocked) angular 2 ionic 2

Tags: angular

I am getting below error:
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/index.json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.**

I have given below is my code.
Any body help me to get resolve this issue.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http ,Response} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class WebserviceProvider {

      constructor(public http: Http) {

        console.log('Hello WebserviceProvider Provider');

      }

     getUser() {

        return this.http.get('http://localhost/index.json')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json());
      }

    }
```

Comment: But i am using the below url it's coming. https://conduit.productionready.io/api/profiles/eric.  Any body help me to use the below url http://localhost/index.json

Comment: Simply use Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi so you can allow CORS.

Comment: OK haseoh, but i am using below url its not coming http://myip/get_emp.php?action=getdetails and how to use local urls?

Comment: Hi Haseoh, I am using chrome advanced rest client below request getting output, but when i am using it in ionic this.http.get not working. showing error ''Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myip/index.json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: As far as I can see, you're using wrong url. You cannot point to localhost, when you taking data from .json you should point the directory of your .json like this: `'assets/index.json'`.

Comment: WOW Excellent. Very Thanks it's working when i am moved my file to assets.

Comment: Hi Haseoh, Kidnly mark this topic as a solved, i dont know how to mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot point your `http.get` url to `localhost`. You're working with .json files, not external API's. This mean, you have to put your .json file into `assets` folder and change this:

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost/index.json')
.map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

To this:

```
return this.http.get('assets/index.json')
.map((res:Response) => res.json());
```